# Problems after adding 'static-site-generator-webpack-plugin' to my project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, plugins

I've just added 'static-site-generator-webpack-plugin' to my project and I'm running into the following errors:

```
ERROR in ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at main:1:224
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:59:29)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInNewContext (vm.js:65:15)
    at module.exports (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/eval/eval.js:69:12)
    at /Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin/index.js:42:22
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:35:21)
    at hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1275:32)
    at _err0 (eval at create (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at /Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:282:11
```

My webpack.config is as follows:

```
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin = require('static-site-generator-webpack-plugin');
var locals = {
  routes: [
     '/',
    '/about'
  ]
};

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry:  './src',
  output: {
    path:  path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd' // this is super important
  },
   module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: __dirname + '/src',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'),
        include: __dirname + '/src'
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin('main', locals.routes),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
  ]
};
```

I'm not sure if this is down to how I've set my webpack.config, however my feeling is that there are issues with using the 'static-site-generator-webpack-plugin' ???

Any help would be much appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `globalObject: 'this'` to your output?
Details [here](https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin/issues/130)